# ReactJS Functional Component "this" keyword problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I searched for similar questions but none fulfilled my doubt. How can I change the "this" to a react functional component in the situation: `<SimpleStorage parent={this}/>` where this Component belongs to a lib (called react-simple-storage) and is written inside a functional component.
All examples I saw were refering to `this.state` or `this.object` or `this.function` but none was about the `this` alone .

```
const Books = () => { 
...  
return <Router>  
            <SimpleStorage parent={this}/> 
            <Routes/>
       </Router>
```

When I try running this way he runs but the console throws:

```
No "parent" prop was provided to react-simple-storage. A parent component's context is required in order to access and update the parent component's state.
            
Try the following: <SimpleStorage parent={this} />
```

How can I set the component State of a functional component? do I have to instantiate a variable in parent component? is something that can be done?

Comment: `Books` is a functional component, which uses an arrow function. Arrow functions do not have their own `this`.

Comment: Don't confuse **function** components with **functional** programming; they are very different things.

Comment: Looks like that library's just out-of-date, there's an abandoned looking PR to support function-based components: https://github.com/ryanjyost/react-simple-storage/pull/30.

Answer (score 1):

This lib is designed to work with class components, so it would be best if you use that type of component.

However, if you look at the source code of the lib you can see that `parent` uses two props: `state` and `setState`, so you can create a state container that will keep all the function component state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
```

and then pass it to the :

```
<SimpleStorage parent={{state, setState}} />
```

Comment: `setState` from `useState` behaves differently to `setState` from a class component so this may not work either

Comment: ok! I'll try, thanks for answering quickly! if it works I'm gonna mark yours as answer

Comment: oh, I am supposed to just create a hook inside the "Books" and send it like you said?